# how to auto drag copy in browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mouse, browser-addons, internet-explorer

I am looking for add-on for browser ..

Its should to do same operation like Linux platfom .. Lik  just drag string . it should get copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/383/

Select text and it's automatically copied to the clipboard. Like Linux or mIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does this by default. I can highlight text and drag it to the address bar or search bar and it will fill. I can drag a link to a tab and the tab will go to that link. It doesn't go to the clipboard though, it just copies it to your target control in the browser. If you want to copy to the clipboard you need to use your answer.